# RX way to get local data and send to remote

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, rx-java, android-room, rx-android

I'm starting with RX and I have a offline app the needs sync data with remote api. What better way to get data from database and send to remote api one by one watching the response of each? Which operators should I use to sequence tasks?

Comment: can you detail a bit more? do you have, say, X records in the DB and you have to perform X api request, one for each item coming from the db? What do you expect to do with the responses?

Comment: X records in the DB and you have to perform X api request, one for each item coming from the db?
YES
What do you expect to do with the responses?
Need update db object and send a feedback to view

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing you can do is something like this (kotlin)

```
     getDataFromDb()
                .map { doNetworkRequest(it) }
                .doOnNext { saveToDb(it) }
                .subscribe()
```

but it really depends on your needs / environment.

You will probably need more mapping in the middle (e.g. to transform the network response to the data that you need to save to the db) and error handling.

Here I assume you don't need the result of saveToDb so I put it as a side effect instead of inside the main observable flow.

Another aspect is how you want to handle the network requests: is it ok to perform them in parallel or not? And maybe use a flatmap

Comment: I'd urge against any work using `doOnXX` operators, you are never aware of any failures of `saveToDb(it)` and you should NOT assume the happy path. It should be incorporated as part of the rx chain, not as a side effect of the chain.

Comment: You make a good point: the failures have to be handled (unless there are reasons not to do so). I tend to treat changes in state (that are by definition a side effect) in the doOnXX, so in general  I'm more inclined in handling the errors in the saveToDb part. 
Obiously if an error on the save is expected to propagate or cause a different behavior in the observable flow that should be handled with a map or something...
So it really depends on the scenario we are considering, I think!
Thanks!